# Which Activator.CreateInstance overload function to call?

Tags: c#-3.0

Which Activator.CreateInstance overload function to call? I have a type returned from 
"Type proxyType = GetProxyType(contractType);" and the constructorinfo is

"[System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo] = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext)}
base {System.Reflection.MemberInfo} = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext)}

[System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo] = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, System.String)}
base {System.Reflection.MethodBase} = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, System.String)}

[System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo] = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, System.String, System.String)}
base {System.Reflection.MethodBase} = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, System.String, System.String)}

[System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo] = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, System.String, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)}
base {System.Reflection.MethodBase} = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, System.String, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)}

[System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo] = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)}
base {System.Reflection.MethodBase} = {Void .ctor(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)}.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the type has a default constructor so `Activator.CreateInstance(proxyType);` should work. If you want to call some other constructor for example the one that take a string parameter you could do this:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(proxyType, "some string parameter");
```

or the one with two string parameters:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(proxyType, "param1", "param2");
```

---

UPDATE:

My mistake there's no parameterless constructor for this type defined. All constructors need at least one argument which is of type [InstanceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontext.aspx). So in order to create an instance of this type you will need to pass at least the instance context. For example if you are in a WCF you could try this:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(
    proxyType, 
    OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext
);
```

Comment: Thanks Darin.  I thought Activator.CreateInstance(proxyType) also.  But it throws me "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."  Stack report is   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
....

Comment: Darin, can we get an InstanceContext to execute proxyType?  OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext seems to be the one in executing the current service.